# LibGDX/Box2D body receiving wrong y coordinates

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

Right I'm working with libGDX/Box2D at the moment and I am completely stumped by a bug I discovered while following this set of tutorials [libGDX](http://williammora.com/a-running-game-with-libgdx-part-1/).

In my game I create an actor and add it to my game stage. The actor is placed on the screen at a given y coordinate. The game simply loops through an animation to simulate running.

The problem is, when I place the actor on the game stage it's y coordinate is somehow given the wrong y coordinate, retrieved using the following code snippet.

```
body.getPosition().y
```

The y coordinate of the actor changes from the correct position of 2.5 to an incorrect position of 3.6 on game startup. The actor then operates as normal from it's updated (incorrect) y position.

I've debugged the bejaysus of my code and I can't see anything that would be causing this. Has anyone come across this kind of behaviour before? Is this some kind of Box2D nuance I am not aware of?

**Game Actor Class**

```
public abstract class GameActor extends Actor {

    protected Body body;
    protected UserData userData;
    protected Rectangle screenRectangle;

    public GameActor() {

    }

    public GameActor(Body body) {
        this.body = body;
        this.userData = (UserData) body.getUserData();
        screenRectangle = new Rectangle();
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);

        if (body.getUserData() != null) {
            updateRectangle();
        } else {
            // This means the world destroyed the body (enemy or runner went out of bounds)
            remove();
        }

    }

    public abstract UserData getUserData();

    private void updateRectangle() {        
        screenRectangle.x = transformToScreen(body.getPosition().x - userData.getWidth() / 2);
        screenRectangle.y = transformToScreen(body.getPosition().y - userData.getHeight() / 2);

        screenRectangle.width = transformToScreen(userData.getWidth());
        screenRectangle.height = transformToScreen(userData.getHeight());
    }

    protected float transformToScreen(float n) {
        return Constants.WORLD_TO_SCREEN * n;
    }
}
```

**Runner Class**

```
public class Runner extends GameActor {

    ...

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

        float x = screenRectangle.x - (screenRectangle.width * 0.1f);
        float y = screenRectangle.y;
        float width = screenRectangle.width * 1.5f;



           stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime();
            batch.draw(runningAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true), x, y - 40, width, screenRectangle.height);
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Try to locate the exact location of the bug by printing body.getPosition().y all the way through the code (like a dichotomy).

Comment: @PârisDouady Good starting point. The Y position is moved to the wrong position in two phases, on the second and third iteration through the act(float delta) method in the game stage.

Comment: It looks like simple mistake but we'll need some code to find it out.

Comment: Yep without code, it'll be hard.

Comment: Remeber to call the actors setBounds method.

Comment: @PârisDouady added code for my actor, any ideas?

Comment: Where is 2.5 declarated ?